Conditions for resultants of bivariate quadratics to be perfect squares
Suppose $$f(x,y)=\sum_{i,j=0\\i+j\in\{0,2\}}^2a_{ij}x^{i}{y^j}$$ and $$g(x,y)=\sum_{i,j=0\\i+j\in\{0,2\}}^2b_{ij}x^{i}{y^j}$$ are two bivariate quadratics over $\mathbb Z[x,y]$.
What are the necessary and sufficient conditions for their resultants to be perfect squares over $\mathbb Z[x]$ and $\mathbb Z[y]$?

@MaxAlekseyev Yes.

I've updated the question to say resultants rather than resultant.

At very least it is necessary that each of the following three numbers is a square:
$$a_{02}^2 b_{20}^2-a_{02} a_{11} b_{11} b_{20}-2 a_{02} a_{20} b_{02} b_{20}+a_{02} a_{20} b_{11}^2+a_{11}^2 b_{02} b_{20}-a_{11} a_{20} b_{02} b_{11}+a_{20}^2 b_{02}^2,$$
$$a_{00}^2 b_{20}^2-a_{00} a_{10} b_{10} b_{20}-2 a_{00} a_{20} b_{00} b_{20}+a_{00} a_{20} b_{10}^2+a_{10}^2 b_{00} b_{20}-a_{10} a_{20} b_{00} b_{10}+a_{20}^2 b_{00}^2,$$
$$a_{00}^2 b_{02}^2-a_{00} a_{01} b_{01} b_{02}-2 a_{00} a_{02} b_{00} b_{02}+a_{00} a_{02} b_{01}^2+a_{01}^2 b_{00} b_{02}-a_{01} a_{02} b_{00} b_{01}+a_{02}^2 b_{00}^2.$$
They represent the common leading coefficient and the trailing coefficients of the resultants.

ADDED. Under the constraints $a_{10}=a_{01}=b_{10}=b_{01}=0$, the resultants represent biquadratic polynomials and their trailing coefficients are squares.
Hence, the necessary and sufficient condition is that the discriminants of the underlying quadratics of resultants are zero.

Hi Max,  maybe correct your solution so that the first and third lines are not identical...

@Derek: Indeed, it was a copy-n-paste error, now corrected. Thanks for noticing!

@MaxAlekseyev I simplified the equations so that there are no linear terms ($a_{10}=a_{01}=b_{01}=b_{10}=0$). Will this yield any necessary and sufficient conditions?

@Turbo: In that case trailing coefficients are algebraic squares, and all we want are zero discriminants. See update.

@MaxAlekseyev Can you elaborate the computations a bit?

@Turbo: For example, the resultant with respect to $y$ equals $u\cdot x^4 + v\cdot x^2 + w^2$, where $u,v,w$ are polynomials in $a$'s and $b$'s, and we want it to have zero discriminant, i.e. $v^2 - 4uw^2=0$. And similarly for the resultant w.r.t. $x$.

@MaxAlekseyev Is there an easy criterion to test if two such no linear term polynomials are algebraically independent?
